# pip3 install ruamel.yaml[jinja2] breaks ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a docker container that has been using ruamel.yaml and ruamel.yaml.jinja2 for a while. Lately it has begun to fail. The following dockerfile reproduces the problem:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update; apt install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install -U pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip install ruamel.yaml
RUN python3 -c "from ruamel.yaml import YAML"

RUN pip install ruamel.yaml[jinja2]
RUN python3 -c "from ruamel.yaml import YAML"
```

The first python3 command succeeds, but the last fails with the following message: ImportError: cannot import name 'YAML'

I have tried specifying earlier versions of ruamel.yaml, but with no success, unless I go all the way back to 0.15.0 (from 2017).

I have also tried different versions of python3.x and pip with no change.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the package ruamel.yaml.jinja2, it has already been reported by @AKX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AKX indicated `ruamel.yaml.jinja2` (which is installed when you do `pip install ruamel.yaml[jinja2]`) was updated to handle jinja2 comments, and this nested package contained a spurious `.pth` file breaking the correct ruamel.yaml install.

There is a new, 0.2.4, version of `ruamel.yaml.jinja2` on PyPI and with that I have been able to build your `Dockerfile` without error.

But in general it is a good idea to fix the version numbers of all the packages you use in your Dockerfile, as @AKX suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It [looks like `ruamel.yaml.jinja2` was updated to version 0.2.3 four days ago](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml.jinja2/src/default/).

I assume that version is broken, so instead install the older version of `ruamel.yaml.jinja2` manually for the time being:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml "ruamel.yaml.jinja2<0.2.3"
```

This seems to work, too.

```
~ $ docker run -it python:3.7-stretch sh -c 'pip install ruamel.yaml[jinja2]; python3 -c "from ruamel.yaml import YAML"'
Collecting ruamel.yaml[jinja2]
Collecting ruamel.yaml.jinja2>=0.2; extra == "jinja2" (from ruamel.yaml[jinja2])
Successfully installed ruamel.yaml-0.15.97 ruamel.yaml.jinja2-0.2.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'YAML' from 'ruamel.yaml' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/__init__.py)

~ $ docker run -it python:3.7-stretch sh -c 'pip install ruamel.yaml "ruamel.yaml.jinja2<0.2.3"; python3 -c "from ruamel.yaml import YAML"'
Collecting ruamel.yaml
Collecting ruamel.yaml.jinja2<0.2.3
Successfully installed ruamel.yaml-0.15.97 ruamel.yaml.jinja2-0.2.2
~ $
```

The longer-term fix is to use a proper dependency version pinning system – I like [`pip-tools`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools).

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much! I actually checked the changelog, but it hadn't been updated since 2017, so I figured there were no recent releases. I see the author updated it just now though!